# How Do I map through an object using react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapping, typeerror

I am creating a dynamic user profile and Am trying to map through an object using React.

I have this code below that fetches user data:

```
   projectFirestore.collection("users").onSnapshot(snapshot => (
     setUserData(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
   ))
 }, [])
/*when the user data is fetched I console.log it
 console.log(userData)
and it returns an array with objects like [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
*/
```

then I search for a specific user using the `array.find()` method:

```
const findTheUser = userData.find(function(data, index) {
   if(data.email === 'minenhlecele@gmail.com')
     return true;
   });  

/* I console.log it
console.log(findTheUser)

and it returns the matching object. the result looks like this  */ 
//{name: 'Minenhle Cele', email: 'minenhlecele@gmail.com', photoUrl: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gj36jZuv0m2rxAN7Fx_78QWHbURpY-YeWb9g=s96-c'}
```

Then what I want is to map through the *findTheUser* object and display the data to the user like

```
{findTheUser.map(({{ name, email}}) => (
           <div className="card">
             <h1>{name}</h1>
             <h2>{email}</h2>
           </div>
            ))}
```

But it keeps throwing the

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `findTheUser` function uses [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which is documented as:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function

So the return value is an element from the array, and not an array itself, and the object doesn't have a `map` method.

So you don't need the loop, and can just do:

```
<div className="card">
  <h1>{findTheUser.name}</h1>
  <h2>{findTheUser.email}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that method but because the object is from the API it takes time to load and react renders initially, so when react checks it finds an empty object then throws this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') "

Comment: Ah, that is second problem indeed. You'll need to pass the item through `setState` (or `useState`) as I've shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65469639) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511632/209103).

Comment: Hey @MinenhleSolsonCele Any update here?

Comment: Yes, Thank You for asking I used the conditional rendering method,  {findTheUser ? <div className="card">
  <h1>{findTheUser.name}</h1>
  <h2>{findTheUser.email}</h2>
</div>  : null}